# How can I retrieve from MongoDB database Eloquent models which contains x elements named

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent

I have to query a MongoDB on a laravel application.
For now I reached to query objects that contains at least one of a named element with this query :

```php
        $result = Schema::whereRaw(['elements.name' => $filter1Element])
        ->when($filter2Element, function ($query, $filter2Element) {
            $query->whereRaw(['elements.name' => $filter2Element]);
        })
        ->when($filter3Element, function ($query, $filter3Element) {
            $query->whereRaw(['elements.name' => $filter3Element]);
        })                    
        ->limit(50)->get();
```

You can see that I have 3 different element filters but I also have 3 differents count filters that corresponds to the minimum number of occurrences of each element filter.

To make it simple I want to retrieve schemas that contain at least $count1 occurrences of $element1, $count2 occurrences of $element2 and $count3 occurrences of $element3.

Do you how can I do this ?